# Ansible if else with vars passing to different playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to pass variables to another playbook through var with an if else condition

```
- hosts: localhost
- import_playbook: merge.yml
  vars:
    variables:
      - "{{ {'test: 'xyz'} if ( flag == true) else  {'test': 'abc'} }}"
```

when I print the value inside merge.yml, it always prints test: abc. I am executing the playbook with the command, ansible-playbook test.yml -e flag=true

Is this a supported syntax? Is there anyway I can use if else with vars ?

Comment: Could you put together a complete example with a merge.yml too?  And include the exact invocation when it's run with flag=true and flag=false, as well as the output?

Comment: I am just printing the values inside merge.yml                                                                      
    `---
    - hosts: localhost
      tasks:
        - debug: msg={{ variables }}
        - debug: msg={{ flag }}`

Comment: `output is ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "test": "abc"
        }
    ]
}
with both flag=true and flag=false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your core problem is that Ansible will treat your `-e "flag=true"` as a string, not a bool. Therefore whatever you set it to, it will always be true.

Also, you have to be careful with what you place inside `{{}}`. It is tempting to think it is full blown Python, when in fact it is Jinja2. Therefore you would be better sticking to pure Jinja2 as much as possible. As an alternative, this works for me:

```
---
- import_playbook: merge.yml
  vars:
    variables: "{{ ( flag | default(false) ) | bool | ternary( {'test': 'xyz'}, {'test': 'abc'} ) }}"
```

- `( flag | default(false) )` provides a default value for `flag` in the event that it is not passed by `-e`. Note, it all needs to be wrapped in `()`, otherwise only the output of `default(false)` will be evaluated by the rest of the statement.
- `bool` forces Ansible to translate the string into a boolean
- `ternary( {'test': 'xyz'}, {'test': 'abc'} )` will use the first value in the case it is passed true and the second if false

A couple of other thoughts:

- you don't need `- hosts: localhost` given you have no tasks attached to it.
- do you have a specific need to use `import_playbook`? A more common pattern would be to have your merge tasks in an include file, rather than a full blown playbook:

playbook.yml

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - include: merge.yml
      vars:
        variables: "{{ ( flag | default(false) ) | bool | ternary( {'test': 'xyz'}, {'test': 'abc'} ) }}"
```

then merge.yml

```
---

- debug:
    var: variables
```

Comment: Thank you. That solution worked. Yes, I agree with hosts:localhost, I don't need them. we are mostly using only URI modules. I am not sure what difference it would make import_playbook vs include_tasks

Comment: import_playbook introduces a series of tasks that are running in an entirely different play. At the very least, that has the inconvenience of having to specify the hosts to target again. It also means play scoped variables defined in the initial play, are not available to the imported tasks. Include by contrast, simply adds more tasks to the existing play, already being targeted to the hosts of the calling play and having access to all its variables. Rule of thumb would be to always pick include, unless you have a specific need for import_playbook.